# SQL Server Bulk Update Changes Column VAlues

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I recently ran an update query on all the rows (Approx. 25k)...
My update query was a simple update as shown here:

```
Update om_Challans set LockType = 'Locked', LockActionDate = getdate(), LockActionBy = 'Query'
```

I have not updated any other column at all.

I also have a trigger that keeps the history in 'om_challans_history' table, so any row that changes is moved to the history table.
I recently noticed that data in about 26 rows have been changed to ZERO automatically by the query. Here is the sample of what i mean:
[image]

Any idea of how is that possible will be greatly appreciated

**Update**

Here is the trigger on om_Challans Table

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[T_CreateUpdateHistory1]
on [dbo].[OM_Challans]
after update
as
    set nocount on

if  ((select [Status] from deleted) LIKE '%FieldData%')
BEGIN
    return
END


insert into om_challans_history (
[Rec_Ltr1] ,
[challan_id] ,
[LockType],
[LockActionDate],
[LockActionBy],
[SamplesSent]
) /* Columns in OM_Challans Table */

select   
i.Rec_Ltr1  ,
i.challan_id  ,
i.LockType,
i.LockActionDate,
i.LockActionBy,
i.SamplesSent /* Old Values of this table */
from
    OM_Challans a
       inner join
    deleted i
        on
            a.sno = i.sno /* Primary Key columns from table A */
```

Comment: Since your trigger is currently broken for multi-row updates, I do not believe that everything needed to answer this question is currently before us (hint `if  ((select [Status] from deleted) LIKE '%FieldData%')` will cause an error when `deleted` contains multiple rows - which is a shame since the rest of the trigger does seem to be correctly built to cope)

Comment: Looking at your query and trigger, This query doesn't seem to be your issue. your `if  ((select [Status] from deleted) LIKE '%FieldData%')` looks misleading. when you update multiple rows this may not work as expected.

Comment: @ughai Well, I didn't see any answer proposed by u. Plus it did take my points (limited points that i have)

Comment: No thats a perfect condition. If the row is not like fielddata, only then is this trigger executed. This is fine !!

Comment: Just as Damien_the_Unbeliever mentioned, if your update touches multiple rows, delete will contain multiple rows and hence `if ((select [Status] from deleted) LIKE '%FieldData%')` will cause an error

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever my point is, why only 26 rows and how come all other 25k records were fine ?

Comment: @ughai and what is the way around ???

Comment: And my point is that the trigger you have shown us will cause an error and force the statement to roll back for any update that affects multiple rows. So how come you claim that that trigger was in place and working when you updated 25k rows?

Comment: If you dont want to audit records with  `[Status] LIKE '%FieldData%'`, put this condition in your `insert into select` and not in an `IF`

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever yes, You are correct. I recall that i got an error when trying to run the bulk update. I disabled this trigger and executed the update. So, trigger is not the culprit. What could have caused the rec_ltr1 to be zero when that query was run.???

Comment: Another update that was also performed whilst the trigger was disabled?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I disabled the trigger and ran the following update Update om_Challans set LockType = 'Locked', LockActionDate = getdate(), LockActionBy = 'Query' ... Thats it.... !!!   Why would it change the values of other columns?

Comment: It didn't. Something else did.

Comment: are you sure no one else could have run any other update?

Comment: In fact, it didn't need to be another update performed when the trigger was disabled - it may be exactly those entries you're seeing in the history table. We now know that those entries *weren't* created by your bulk update, since the trigger was disabled. If there's not enough information in your history table to work on how/when those entries were created, well, that's a separate issue. I don't see that this question can be answered in any way from what you've given us (most of it now being redundant)

Comment: hmmm... I also think that... Let me re-think on what could it be !!! Thanks for your help